# Android ActionBar color

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to change color in my whole application.

In my **AndroidManfiest.xml** I've got proper code:

```
<application
      android:label="@string/AppName"
      android:icon="@drawable/Icon"
      android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
      android:name="MyAppName"
      android:allowBackup="true">
```

And in **values** folder, I've got **app_theme.xml**:

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionBarColor</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

It works very strange... I've got my actionbar color **only during application loading**, after this returns to the default color.

**SOLUTION**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AnnotatedActivity {

@Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(getSupportActionBar()!=null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#009688")));
            getSupportActionBar().show();
        }
    }

}
```

**and every activity must extends BaseActivity.**

Regards

Comment: Have you defined different theme for your activity?

Comment: @PrerakSola No, every activity have the same theme.

Comment: show me you manifest file

Comment: what are you using in your activity? context or getApplicationContext?

Comment: @agilob context. 
mr.icetea I will edit post, just moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 // not able to get action  
    if(getActionBar()!=null){// actionbar is not null 
       // now  change color of action bar 
       getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#E77A2B")));
       //put any color in parseColor.
       getActionBar().show();
     }else{
         System.out.println("getActionbar is null");

     }
```

Comment: I added this code in **protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)** method in my BaseActivity and each subsequent activity extends it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

**Since you are using AppCompat library**

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_name</item>
```

to set color to ActionBar

So you default Theme will be

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_name</item>

    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
</style>
```

Comment: That could be nice, but "No resource found that matches the given name". There's no attribute "colorPrimary".